# kendo-knockout + bootstrap 4 validation

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, bootstrap-4, knockout-validation

I am using kendo-knockout for some components but it seems that knockout validation does not add the errorElementClass value to the kendo widgets so the red border and error message color are not set

```
ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: false,
    errorElementClass: 'is-invalid',
    decorateElement: true,
    decorateInputElement: true,
    messagesOnModified: true
});

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.startDate = ko.observable(null).extend({ required: true });
    self.endDate = ko.observable(null).extend({ required: true });
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

    this.validate = function() {
        self.errors.showAllMessages(true);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());




<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="date" class="col-3 col-form-label">Date</label>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="date" data-bind="kendoDatePicker: startDate">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            <span data-bind="validationMessage: startDate"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tqrv513g/

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why knockout cannot add the is-invalid class to your kendo date pickers is because they have been nested in spans by kendo widgets. There are two ways to do it but I would recommend to:

Show the validation messages on load and bind a custom validator that will add the is-invalid class to your kendo input for date pickers and add another class to the parent kendo span that is currently wrapping the datepicker inpput box:

```
    self.getInvalidCssClass =  function (obs) {

       var parentContext = $(".k-picker-wrap");

       var cssClass = '';
       if (!obs.isValid()) {
           parentContext.addClass('kendo-invalid-date');
           cssClass = 'is-invalid'
       } else {
          parentContext.removeClass('kendo-invalid-date');
       }
        return cssClass;
    };
```

Html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label for="date" class="col-3 col-form-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="date" data-bind="kendoDatePicker: startDate, css: getInvalidCssClass(startDate)">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                <span data-bind="validationMessage: startDate"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="date2" class="col-3 col-form-label">End date</label>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="endDate" data-bind="kendoDatePicker: endDate, css: getInvalidCssClass(endDate)">
            <span class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: endDate"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.kendo-invalid-date {border-color: Red;}
```

I've updated your fiddle [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/habyphael/tqrv513g/30/).

All you have to do is to load your main style sheet after the kendo style sheets.